# MySQL: How to SELECT only three of each differing x-column-name

Tags: php, mysql, limit-per-group

I want to display my blogs in a very future proof way. So I need to make a query that will reference new blog types if they are created. Hence the x-column-name. In this case that's blogType. This select query should contain the blog information for all blog types, but for each blog type get 3 Blogs. It's kind of confusing so this is why I am reiterating!

I have done a bit of work already in googling how to limit the results. Shown below:

```
 $query = 'SELECT * FROM blogs
              ORDER BY dateWritten
              ASC LIMIT 3';
```

I'll be outputting the results to blog_rss.php using an array and a foreach loop. I get the array from a function like this:

```
function get_Recent_Blogs() {
    global $db;
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM blogs
              ORDER BY dateWritten
              ASC LIMIT 3';
    try {
        $statement = $db->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $statement->closeCursor();
        return $result;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $error_message = $e->getMessage();
        display_db_error($error_message);
    }
}
```

It's not too important but at least it gives you some context.

```
    SELECT *
    FROM (
         SELECT b.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.blogType ORDER BY b.blogID DESC) as rn
         FROM blogs b
         ) x
    WHERE x.rn <= 3
    ORDER BY x.blogType, x.blogID DESC';
```

So I've done my best to implement the solution but I'm getting some errors. I'm not sure if I should start a new post for this one or not but the code above is what I used and this is the error I'm getting:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; it seems the error is around: '( PARTITION BY b.blogType ORDER BY b.dateWritten DESC ' at line 7
```

Comment: What is your MySQL version?

Comment: 8.0.13 is my version

Comment: So let's clarify: You need a query which returns three most recent articles per blog type. Is that correct?

Comment: That's exactly correct. Yes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your MySQL version supports window functions, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()`, which will enumerate your entries per blog type. Then you just need to pick the first three rows per type.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT b.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.type ORDER BY b.dateWritten DESC) as rn
    FROM blogs b
) x
WHERE x.rn <= 3
ORDER BY x.type, x.dateWritten DESC -- adjust as needed
```

Notes:

- I assume that the blog type is determined by the `type` column. Adjust it if needed.
- You should use `DESC` instead of `ASC`, since you want to get the most recent entries.
- I would rather use an AUTO_INCEMENT `id` column instead of `dateWritten` for sorting. That is more reliable, since a DATE or even a TIMESTAMP can have duplicates.

For older versions which don't support window functions I would first fetch all types and generate a UNION ALL query. With PDO it could be something like the following:

```
$types = $db
       ->query('SELECT DISTINCT type from blogs ORDER BY type')
       ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);

$subqueries = array_map(function($type){
    return '(SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE type = ? ORDER by dateWritten DESC LIMIT 3)';
}, $types);

$query = implode(' UNION ALL ', $subqueries) . ' ORDER BY type, dateWritten DESC';

$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->execute($types);
$result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This will generate the following query:

```
(SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE type = ? ORDER by dateWritten DESC LIMIT 3)
UNION ALL
...
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE type = ? ORDER by dateWritten DESC LIMIT 3)
ORDER BY type, dateWritten DESC
```

Note 1: Even though two queries are executed, given a composite index on `(type, dateWritten)` this can still be faster than other solutions. When you have a couple of blog types and many articles per type, this can even be faster than the ROW_NUMBER() solution.

Note 2: I would usually have a separate table for types, and the `blogs` table would reference the primary key `type_id` column. In that case the first query would be `SELECT type_id from blog_types`, and the subqueries would have the condition `WHERE type_id = ?`.

Comment: Thank you! I am very newbish in MySQL so this is very helpful. I appreciate it!

Comment: Wouldn't happen to know what's wrong with the syntax here would you?

Comment: @DanielJ.Dunevant Do you get an error? It works for me here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/s3qAyCDo7ScQorPg98sCMt/0

Comment: I did... :( In testing the code that is valid in 5.7 I got the error of: "SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: no parameters were bound." The fiddle code is for 8.0 though so it doesn't work for me currently.

Comment: @DanielJ.Dunevant You wrote your version is 8.0.13, but the error in question with "near ( PARTITION" tells me that it's not. However - That's why I wrote a second solution. "no parameters were bound" - Seems that you've changed something. Be sure you pass the types here: `$statement->execute($types);`

Comment: I'm very new. I did realize that later on I was on 5.7 but neglected to mention it! Also you are again right! I didn't  put the types  there!   I really need to look more closely! 
It now functions perfectly! Thank you so much for helping me through my ignorance. Now I'm hopefully slightly less so!